# How can I print my name n times in bash script?

Tags: bash

I have to make bash script that will print my name as many times as i put number.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Please enter a number"
read n
until $n
do
echo "$n My name"
done
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question a professional or programming enthusiast would ask.

Comment: @oguzismail That ship has sailed. Unlke many questions, this at least shows *some* attempt to solve the problem; the only thing missing is how to modify `n` over the course of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain an explicit counter. For example, here's one that starts with `n` and counts down to 0.

```
echo "Please enter a number"
read n
i=$n
until [ "$i" -lt 1 ]
do
echo "$i My name"
i=$((i-1))
done
```

This will work in any POSIX-compliant shell; since you are using `bash`, you can use a C-style `for` loop to maintain the counter.

```
echo "Please enter a number"
read n
for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do
    echo "$i My name"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I just started with this and this was my first assignment. I manage to figure it out yesterday...your answer is much simpler...I did it like this:  declare -i num1
echo "Please enter a number"
read num1
declare -i COUNTER
COUNTER=num1
while [ $COUNTER -gt 0]; do
echo "$COUNTER My name"
done
exit

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `declare -i`; it doesn't really gain you anything.

Answer (score 0):

With two building blocks:

### For loops

```sh
for i in some whitespace-separated words
do
    echo "Hello, $i"
done
```

This will execute the block inside the loop for every word. It will output the following:

```
Hello, some
Hello, whitespace-separated
Hello, words
```

### Ranges

The term `{1..3}` will get replaced by `1 2 3` at runtime.

Now you know how to execute something 20 times:

```sh
for i in {1..20}
do
    something
done
```

Comment: Neither of these will help if the number of times is not known until the user inputs it, as the OP is asking.